# Checking Google Appengine Cron status programmatically

Tags: google-app-engine, cron, gcloud

I would like to programmatically check the status of Cron tasks on appengine.

Here is the URL I use to see it manually:
https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/taskqueues?project=PROJECT_ID&moduleId=default&tab=CRON

Is there any API or command line tool (gcloud/gsutil) for that? I searched and wasn't able to find anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the TaskQueue API to fetch queue statistics. For example, here is documentation about the fetch queue statistics method in the Java API client library:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/taskqueue/Queue.html#fetchStatistics--